# how to draw a simple bar chart with labels in python using matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have a data like below

```
>>>x = [transactional,promotional]  
>>>y = [3198293, 189910]
```

i need to draw a simple bar chart? how can i?

this is how i tried

```
>>>import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>plt.bar(x, y ,width=0.90)
```

simply i need to plot a bar chart with the labels and x-axis is x and y-axis is y.
tried some methods but it is
showing some random diagram....please help me on this.

Comment: Please read the docs, and indicate what "methods" you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below produces the following graph:

[image: graph]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Specify data / labels
y = [3198293, 189910]
xlabels = ['transactional','promotional']
bar_width = 0.90

x = np.arange(len(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, width=bar_width)
ax.set_xticks(x + (bar_width/2.0))
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
plt.show()
```

This is just a basic example, there are much more detailed examples at http://matplotlib.org/examples/.

You may be interested specifically in [barchart_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)